# missing packages in lucene 4.0 snapshot

Tags: lucene

anybody knows why there is no QueryParser, nor IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(25000) and some more in Lucene 4.0 Snapshot? 
I'm having hard time to port the code to this newer version, though I'm following the code as given here: http://search-lucene.com/jd/lucene/overview-summary.html

How do I find the missing packages, and how do I get them? As the snapshop jar doesn't contain all the features..

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene has been re-architectured, and some classes which used to be in the core module are now in submodules. You will now find the [QueryParser stuff](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/modules/queryparser/src/java/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/) in the queryparser submodule. Similarly, lots of useful analyzers, tokenizers and tokenfilters have been moved to the [analysis](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/modules/analysis/) submodule.

Regarding IndexWriter, the maximum field length option has been deprecated, it is now recommended to wrap an analyzer with [LimitTokenCountAnalyzer](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/modules/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/LimitTokenCountAnalyzer.java) (in the analysis submodule) instead.

Comment: thanks for you answer, it took me sometime last night to figure it out. Can you provide an example as on how to use this `LimitTokenCountAnalyzer`